# Unable to open visual basic project

Tags: vb6

I've made some changes in a visual basic 6.0 project. When I try to open it later, I'm getting a dialog with the following error.

> Errors during load. Refer to '' for details.

Its failing to load one form. In the log file its saying that `frmFileName.fr` could not be loaded. Please note the file extension is shown as .fr, not .frm in the log.

How to resolve this?

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: Should this really be tagged VBA?

Answer (score 3):

Open your applicable vbp file with a text editor and look for the entry:

`Form=frmFileName.frm`

Make sure is says 'frm' instead of 'fr'. Perhaps this file got modified or corrupted. Also, make sure the form is in the same directory, or, if not, that the vbp references the correct path, and that the actual file is correctly named 'frmFileName.frm'.

If this doesn't work. Try removing the entry from the vbp, and then after saving and opening the project, you could try importing the form file.